# Salesforce Permission set

Tags: salesforcedx, permission-sets

Can we give Modify Metadata and Manage Prompts permission for the user from permission set in the Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do it, you should go to:

> Setup -> Permission Sets -> {{Your set}} -> System Permissions -> Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions / Manage Prompts